# Why does Clang fail to find a viable constructor?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, clang++, template-argument-deduction

Why does the following code produce **error: no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'R'**?

I've tried compiling this [code](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/-v5TuD) on gcc.godbolt.org using all versions of Clang starting from 6.0.0 and up. They all produce the same error message. However, the code compiles with GCC 8.1 and later. Could this be a bug in Clang? Or maybe in GCC?

Compiler options used: -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -Wextra

```cpp
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
int fn(T&)
{
    return 0;
}

struct S {};

template <typename T>
struct R
{
    using F = std::function<int(T&)>;

    R(T& _t, F _fn)
        : t_{_t}
        , fn_{_fn}
    {
        fn_(t_);
    }

    T& t_;
    F fn_;
};

int main()
{
    S s;

    // Why does Clang fail on 'fn<S>'?
    // If I wrap 'fn<S>' in curly braces (e.g. {fn<S>}), it works.
    R r{s, fn<S>};

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The solution mentioned in that post fixes the issue for Clang, but why does the posted code work with GCC?

Comment: Sounds like a GCC bug.  Making it a non-deduced context makes the code compare in both compilers anyway :)

Comment: Thanks!  I think the other post answers my question.  I'll see about reporting this to the GCC team.